# Pandas Group By Forward Rolling Days Interval

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I have daily stock data that includes Symbol, Date, Close for multiple Symbols. I'm attempting to accomplish the following:

1. Find the Forward Rolling Min Close value
2. With a Window size = 5 **calendar** days (not 5 rows).
3. Grouped by Symbol

Data

```
Date, Symbol, Close
2021-01-01, AAPL, 10
2021-01-02, AAPL, 12
2021-01-03, AAPL, 3
2021-01-04, AAPL, 20
2021-01-05, AAPL, 15
2021-01-01, MSFT, 12
2021-01-02, MSFT, 20
2021-01-03, MSFT, 12
2021-01-04, MSFT, 20
2021-01-05, MSFT, 20
```

Current Attempt:

```
df.assign(min_roll=df.iloc[::-1].groupby(df['Symbol']).rolling(on='Date',window='5D',min_periods=1)['Close'].min().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(0,drop=True))
```

Sorted by date descending for Forward Rolling by Date `df.iloc[::-1]`

When applying the `rolling(on='Date'`, and `window='5D'` I get an error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

Without the time interval component, the code works as expected for 5 rows (not calendar days)

```
df.assign(min_roll=df.iloc[::-1].groupby(df['Symbol']).rolling(5,min_periods=1)['Close'].min().sort_index(level=1).reset_index(0,drop=True))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not easy to understand your question without an example of your dataset. can you please display or print df so we can see what the data looks like

Comment: Yes I just updated the post

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to specify a window, which goes through the index, as `5D`, without having a datetime index.

To solve this, use this:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

I got this when when applying the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05'],
    'Symbol': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'MSFT', 'MSFT', 'MSFT', 'MSFT'],
    'Close': [10, 12, 3, 20, 15, 12, 20, 12, 20, 20]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df = df.sort_values(by=['Symbol', 'Date'])
df['Forward_Rolling_Min'] = df.groupby('Symbol')['Close'].rolling(window='5D').min().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(df)
```

Results:

```
           Symbol  Close  Forward_Rolling_Min
Date                                         
2021-01-01   AAPL     10                 10.0
2021-01-02   AAPL     12                 10.0
2021-01-03   AAPL      3                  3.0
2021-01-04   AAPL     20                  3.0
2021-01-05   AAPL     15                  3.0
2021-01-01   MSFT     12                 12.0
2021-01-02   MSFT     20                 12.0
2021-01-03   MSFT     12                 12.0
2021-01-04   MSFT     20                 12.0
2021-01-05   MSFT     20                 12.0
```

So as a summary: your problem was with the index of the df, if my semantics do not work for you, maybe my syntax will ;)

Comment: @greenguy - this solution wrongly assign values to ouput.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) instead `assign`:

```
out = (df.merge(df.iloc[::-1].groupby(df['Symbol'])
                .rolling(on='Date',window='5D',min_periods=1)['Close']
                .min().rename('min_roll'), on=['Symbol','Date']))
print(out)
        Date Symbol  Close  min_roll
0 2021-01-01   AAPL     10       3.0
1 2021-01-02   AAPL     12       3.0
2 2021-01-03   AAPL      3       3.0
3 2021-01-04   AAPL     20      15.0
4 2021-01-05   AAPL     15      15.0
5 2021-01-01   MSFT     12      12.0
6 2021-01-02   MSFT     20      12.0
7 2021-01-03   MSFT     12      12.0
8 2021-01-04   MSFT     20      20.0
9 2021-01-05   MSFT     20      20.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. It looks like all you changed was using merge and renaming? Why would merge work but not assign?

Comment: @greenguy - reason is because `groupby+rolling` create `MultiIndex`, so cannot easy join to original, need merge by both columns `['Symbol','Date']`. Also `rename` is used for set new column name

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me. variable is column containing name of stock. Day is the column containing dates. Value is stock price.

```
stock_new_data['mean']=stock_new_data.groupby(["Day","variable"])['value'].rolling(window=5,min_periods=1).mean().reset_index(level=0,drop=True).reset_index(drop=True)
stock_new_data
```

Comment: Thanks but this will calculate over trading days, not calendar days, since I dont have weekends in my data set.